# Need help trying to implement react-native-firebase to my detached expo project

Tags: objective-c, xcode, firebase, react-native

As title says I tried add some code in my detached expo project to receive push notification using react-native-firebase.

I kinda new to obj-c and iOS environment, so this could be silly question. But I couldn't find the solution in stackoverflow.

so my question is this: can I add UIResponder protocol with my existing protocol: EXStandaloneAppDelegate?

my AppDelegate.m

```
#import "AppDelegate.h"

#import <Firebase.h>
#import <React/RCTBridge.h>
#import <React/RCTBundleURLProvider.h>
#import <React/RCTRootView.h>

@implementation AppDelegate

// Put your app delegate methods here. Remember to also call methods from EXStandaloneAppDelegate superclass
// in order to keep Expo working. See example below.



- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions
{

    [FIRApp configure];
    RCTBridge *bridge = [[RCTBridge alloc] initWithDelegate:self launchOptions:launchOptions];

// here the problem merges: Sending 'AppDelegate *const __strong' to parameter of incompatible type 'id<RCTBridgeDelegate>'


    RCTRootView *rootView = [[RCTRootView alloc] initWithBridge:bridge
                                                     moduleName:@"push"
                                              initialProperties:nil];

    rootView.backgroundColor = [[UIColor alloc] initWithRed:1.0f green:1.0f blue:1.0f alpha:1];

    self.window = [[UIWindow alloc] initWithFrame:[UIScreen mainScreen].bounds];
    UIViewController *rootViewController = [UIViewController new];
    rootViewController.view = rootView;
    self.window.rootViewController = rootViewController;
    [self.window makeKeyAndVisible];
    return [super application:application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:launchOptions];
}

- (NSURL *)sourceURLForBridge:(RCTBridge *)bridge
{
#if DEBUG
    return [[RCTBundleURLProvider sharedSettings] jsBundleURLForBundleRoot:@"index" fallbackResource:nil];
#else
    return [[NSBundle mainBundle] URLForResource:@"main" withExtension:@"jsbundle"];
#endif
}




@end
```

my AppDelegate.h

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>
#import <ExpoKit/EXStandaloneAppDelegate.h>
#import <React/RCTBridgeDelegate.h>
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>

@interface AppDelegate : EXStandaloneAppDelegate <UIApplicationDelegate> UIResponder <UIApplicationDelegate, RCTBridgeDelegate>

    @property (nonatomic, strong) UIWindow *window;

// this gives me an error
'Prefix attribute must be followed by an interface or protocol'

@end
```

@interface Appdelegate should takes UIresponder protocol, not only EXStandaloneAppDelegate.